# IBM Watson Assistant: How to avoid accidental key in information

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

[image: JSON Conditions]**Problem**

I am working on the **Welcome** dialog node where the bot asked for the user's name. The,n user accidentally entered **Hi** or **hello** but the bot recognize hi or hello as the name.

*Note: I've a variable call name to capture and store the user's name and to call it out as and when is required.*

**What is Expected**

Basically, I want the bot to recognize hi/hello as greetings and respond accordingly and then ask for the user's name. I've already turned on digression and return back but it is still not working.

How can I react to the accidental Hi or Hello?

[image: Structure]
[image: Evaluate Condition]
[image: Slot Configuration]
[image: Slot Configuration Cond']

Hi i've added some pic to understand the issue that i'm facing. You may give your suggestions.

Hello all, i'm still trying ways to improve, i've attached the json pic but why it's showing error like response can only contacin properties =:output,output.generic,context,actions, am i doing something wrong here ?

Comment: Have you used the best practice to confirm with the user that the input is correct? Ask if "Hi" is the correct name and if not let the user correct it.

Comment: Dear Henrik, thank you for the prompt reply. appreciate it. how do i go about on doing that user confirmation ?

Comment: There are samples in the Watson Assistant docs. Respond to the input by stating what was entered (the context variable)

Comment: i'm kind of new to this, please pardon me. i check thru the docs but i guess i'm using the wrong keyword. would be happy if you could share me some links. thank you

Answer (score 0):

See this example from the [IBM Watson Assistant documentation on using slots to capture input and then adding a confirmation slot](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-tutorial-slots-complex#tutorial-slots-complex-confirmation-slot). The confirmation slot would print the provided input and ask as yes / no question if that is correct.

In your case, you would ask "Have I got this right as your name? 'Hi'". The user would need to respond with "no" and you could jump back to entering the name.

Comment: Hi there, sorry for the late reply as i was caught with course. i tried the following from the link given but i'm stuck with the "Respond with Yes to indicate that you want the reservation to be made as-is, or No to indicate that you do not." even if i enter yes or not the respond is the same.

Comment: hi henrik, i tried the slot but i don't see the option to jump to another node. the only options i can see is "move on", "Clear slot and prompt again", and "Skip  to response". besides that i'm kind of stuck with the option even if i input yes and no the answer or result is the same. appreciate if you could help me out. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can stick to what Henrik said. However, if you want your Assistant to answer the greeting you can also add a Handler (if you are using slots). You would create an #intent with different greetings and let the Assistant check for it and define an answer. After that Assistant would ask again for the name. (The option is called "Manage Handlers")

This video explains it pretty good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mrHgLCNraf8

Comment: Hi warkus, thanks for the video. very informative. i tried the following and referencing from the IBM guide but then i'm stuck with the answer and i can't find the jump to option in the slot settings